# DIV visible every minute for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I need you to help me.
Surely for you it is easy but ... it took a while and I can't.

I have a DIV always visible, and I would like another DIV to appear every minute for 10 seconds, and then hide until it had to come out again (after a minute has passed since the other one was hidden). So repeat it endlessly.

How could I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the role of the first DIV in your question? What was your attempt. Please show your attempt (code) and where you are stuck? Did you read about `setTimeout`?

Comment: Post relevant parts of the code that you've tried, show the errors you got, and the effort you made. SO is NOT a: write code service.

Comment: I have a main DIV with a video and I want every minute to show another DIV with the time for 10 seconds and then disappear.
Once it disappears after 1 minute the time reappears, and so on indefinitely.

I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a recursive function that uses two setTimeout() and  calls itself so it will wait the full minute after being hidden before starting again

```
function showHide() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // show element here

    setTimeout(() => {
        //hide element here then            
        // start all over by calling same function
        showHide();
      }, 10 * 1000);

  }, 60 * 1000);
}

// call it once to start
showHide()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setTimeout()` function together with the `setInterval()` function for this task.

```js
setInterval(()=>{
   //make the div visible here
   setTimeout(()=>{
     //Make div invisible here
   }, 10 * 1000)//This is in milliseconds
}, 60 * 1000)
```

The `setInterval()` function will be executed continuously each minute.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this way the second round is getting shorter and shorter.
It begins at 60 seconds and at 10 it is removed, but the next does not start at 60 since it is removed, but it appears at 50

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setTimeout` and `setInterval` for displaying or hiding particular div. You can refer [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Moreover, you can hide and show the div using JS as,

To hide:

`document.getElementById('<DIV_ID_HERE>').style.display = 'none'`

To show:

`document.getElementById('<DIV_ID_HERE>').style.display = 'block'`